# Xhr request disables other AJAX requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

So I noticed a bug on my site I was testing tonight.  It happens on an image page, and the page works fine and I can change status of the images (primary or secondary) and delete them, navigate around to other pages, etc.

So the part I navigate around with is (basically, it grabs the current page, requested page, and whatever formdata which is specific to that page, validated server-side)

```
...
var formData = $("#eventForm").serializeArray();
//testing bit for xhr happens here (explained later)
$.ajax({
    url: "pageTemplates/createEvent.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {page:page,formData:formData},
    cache:false,
    success: function(result) {
        $(".Account-data").html(result);
    }
})
...
```

But once I upload an image I can't navigate to any other pages. Image upload bit here:

```
...
 var imgData = new FormData();
$.ajaxSetup({
    data:{type:type}
})
imgData.append('imageFile',$("#imageFile")[0].files[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: "pageTemplates/imageUpload.php",
    type: "POST",
    xhr: function() {
        myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        return myXhr;
    },
    data: imgData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(result) {
        $("#imagesData").append(result);
        $("#imageFile").html("<input type='file' name='imageFile' id='imageFile' onchange='imageUpdate(this)' />");
    }
});
...
```

I've managed to trace the issue down to setting the xhr, and testing for the xhr shows that it still exists even after the image upload has occurred.

Is there a way for me to disable the XHR after the image upload has occurred? Or some way to unset it? Or is there an entirely different way I should be handling this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out.  I realized a mirrored image upload was working just fine elsewhere.  So I basically just copied/pasted that code and altered the form index and it worked.

So this:

```
var imgData = new FormData();
$.ajaxSetup({
    data:{type:type}
})
imgData.append('imageFile',$("#imageFile")[0].files[0]);
```

got changed into:

```
var formData = new FormData($("form")[1]);
```

which is going to be slightly more difficult to maintain in some ways, easier to maintain in others.